# Analytic continuation past the disk

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

So I just proved that if $f$ is analytic on $\overline{\mathbb D}$, and $f(\partial\mathbb D) \subset \partial \mathbb D$, then it extends to a rational function on $\mathbb C$. What if we weaken this to $f$ analytic on only $\mathbb D$ and continuously extendable to $\overline{\mathbb D}$? My reasoning on the first part was that since $\overline{\mathbb D}$ is compact, and the set of zeros of a holomorphic funciton are isolated, $f$ must have only finitely many zeros on $\mathbb D$, and therefore

$$F(z) = \frac{1}{\overline{f(\overline z ^{-1}) }} \text{ when }z \in \mathbb D^c $$

$$F(z) = f(z) \text{ otherwise}$$

has only finitely many poles on $\mathbb D^c$, and extends analytically to a function on $\mathbb C$ (using a symmetry principle, if $f$ is analytic on both sides of a circle, and continuously extendable to the circle, then it is analytic on the circle), and therefore must be rational (if a meromorphic function on $\mathbb C$ has finite zeros and poles, then it must be rational).

With the weaker hypothesis, only way for it to fail to be rational is if it has an infinite number of zeros $\{a_n\}$ in $\mathbb D$, but we can't have this, because then there is a subsequential limit $a_{n_k} \to a \in \overline{\mathbb D}$ where by continuity, $0 = \lim f(a_{n_k}) = f(a)$, and either $a \in \mathbb D$, contradicting the analiticity of $f$, or $a \in \partial \mathbb D$ and $|f(a)| \ne 1$ where $|a| = 1$ contradicting the hypothesis.

But I have a sneaking suspicion that this reasoning is wrong somewhere, because my understanding of complex analysis isn't so great, and the question is phrased in a way to suggest that it is wrong. Question: Is my proof correct?

Comment: It's a little difficult to discern what your proof exactly is, since you don't clearly separate where the remarks about the case of a function analytic on a neighbourhood of the closed disk end and where the argument for a function analytic in the open disk and continuous on the closed disk begins, but it is correct. The crucial points, that $f$ can have only finitely many zeros in the disk, and that a continuous function on a neighbourhood of the unit circle that is analytic on the complement of the circle is analytic on the neighbourhood were rightly mentioned.

Comment: There, I cleaned it up slightly. My issue is that in searching, I've only seen this question with f being analytic on the closed disk, not on the open disk and continuously extensible to the closed disk, so that is a weak indication that that hypothesis is necessary.

Comment: I thought your argument for the "weaker" case began earlier. If $f$ is analytic in a neighbourhood of the disk, you don't need to invoke "if $f$ is analytic on both sides of a circle, and continuously extendable to the circle, then it is analytic on the circle", you only need that for the weaker assumptions.

Comment: Right, of course. Well, it seems like the weaker one is still correct. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the weaker one is still correct. You can even weaken the assumptions further. It suffices that you demand $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \lvert f(z_n)\rvert = 1$$ for every sequence $(z_n)$ in $\mathbb{D}$ with $\lvert z_n\rvert \to 1$.